# RecyclerView optimization issues

Tags: android, optimization, android-recyclerview

I've noticed some RV performance issues.
I have a RecyclerView with some amount of items. When I launch my Fragment with RV and trying to scroll it for the first time I see some lags. I'll attach a GIF with active GPU profiling at the end of this question.
As you can see, I have a huge FPS drop when I start scrolling then it becomes smooth. So my question is -

Is it possible to optimise this process? I tried the following:

**1. To create View for all my ViewHolders once:**

private var itemView: View? = null

```
override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    if (itemView == null) {
        itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.rv_contact_item, parent, false)
    }
    return ContactViewHolder(itemView)
}
```

But it's not possible, cuz this view will be attached to it's parent with first `onCreateViewHolder` call and I'm getting crash "Detach your view from parent first".

**2. Create ViewHolders in background thread.**

Doesn't do anything too.

I know there's a possibility to create View programmatically, but will it work as intended? I have a pretty difficult View, so it would take some time to try it.

[image]

**UPD:**

My XML for single item:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn_contact"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <com.myapp.custom.AvatarView
        android:id="@+id/v_avatar"
        android:layout_width="56dp"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:transitionName="chat_avatar_transition"
        tools:background="@color/pale_red">

        <com.myapp.custom.UserStatusView
            android:id="@+id/v_user_status"
            android:layout_width="18dp"
            android:layout_height="18dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"/>
    </com.myapp.custom.AvatarView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_conference"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:baselineAlignBottom="true"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_vector_conference"/>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_name"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                android:transitionName="chat_name_transition"
                tools:text="Title" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_contact_subtitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/text_light"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:lines="1"
            tools:text="Subtitle" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_last_message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_message_direction"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginEnd="3dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_vector_arrow_right" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_last_message"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textColor="@color/text_light"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:lines="1"
                tools:text="Hello!" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_birthday"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_vector_birthday" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_app_type"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_vector_mobile" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_important_messages"
                android:layout_width="24dp"
                android:layout_height="24dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_vector_flag" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/iv_message_status"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_vector_checked" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv_unread_counter"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minHeight="24dp"
                android:minWidth="24dp"
                android:padding="3dp"
                android:background="@drawable/shape_rect_rounded_12dp_blue_regular"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
                tools:text="10" />
        </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**UPD2:**

My bind() method:

```
fun bind(contact: ContactModel) {
            avatarView.apply {
                initialize(
                    contact.id,
                    contact.avatar,
                    contact.fullName)
            }
            ivConference.visibility = if (ContactType.CONFERENCE == contact.type)
                View.VISIBLE
            else
                View.GONE

            tvName.text = contact.fullName
            tvContactSubtitle.text = contact.subtitle
            contact.lastMessageDirection?.let { direction ->
                llLastMessage.visible

                ivLastMessageDirection.setImageDrawable(
                    VectorDrawableCompat.create(
                        itemView.context.resources,
                        direction.icon,
                        null)
                )
                tvLastMessage.text = contact.lastMessage
            } ?: llLastMessage.invisible
            ivBirthday.visibility = if (contact.isBirthdayInc) {
                View.VISIBLE
            } else
                View.GONE

            ivImportantMessages.visibility = if (contact.hasImportantMessages)
                View.VISIBLE
            else
                View.GONE

            if (contact.unreadCounter == 0) {
                tvUnreadCounter.gone
            } else {
                tvUnreadCounter.visible
                tvUnreadCounter.text = contact.unreadCounter.toString()
            }
        }
```

Comment: You only need `return ContactViewHolder(inflatercode...)` in your `onCreateViewHolder` because your `ContactViewHolder` will be cached anyway.

Comment: Include your XML of single RV row item and onBindViewHolder() function

Comment: What are you using for profiling as seen in the photo?

Comment: @TomasJablonskis done, you can take a look, it's pretty heavy.

Comment: @JasonStack default Android feature from Developer's menu.

Comment: You have quite much ImageViews, try commenting them in XML and then test your app again. If it still lags, then the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Ok so if you comment out the  entire `contact.lastMessageDirection?.let {` function and `avatarView.apply {` function do you notice any performance improvement?

Comment: No, it looks a little bit better if I comment out entire bind(). Anyway, I did some profiling and it looks like LayoutInflater causes performance issues

Answer (score 0):

That is because the quality of the image you've used is too high for so many item which takes time to optimize.

Please convert your images to WebP format for better performance.

Hope it helps.

Comment: These pics are created with Android Drawable Shape. I tried to remove avatars at all tho, it doesn't change anything.

Comment: Okay, What is the format of the pics..? I mean extension.